# Skip lists, why we need more than one insertion?

Tags: c++, list, algorithm, skip-lists

I was learning about [skip lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) and there is something I couldn't understand.

When we insert a new node we throw a coin and if we get 1 we insert the node another time on the upper level and so on until we get 0 we stop.

But why we need this at all?

Comment: This question sounds a lot like "Why is a skip list structured like a skip list?" which is a tautology. Are you asking "What is the point of a skip list?" You can do a binary search on a contiguous array, but not on a linked list. This is what linked lists need to do to get that kind of capability. The random "coin flip" on insertion seems to be a way to pick splits roughly half the time without the cost-complexity of something like a balanced red-black tree.

Comment: The implementation details [on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) for a skip list explain fairly well the reasoning behind the coin flip for promotion. In short, the random nature of the flip is what builds the data structure as pseudo-balanced.

Comment: Without doing the extra insertion there would be no skipping in the skip list.

Answer (score 1):

If you only add one layer to the skip list, you get an ordered linked list, where each node is connected to its next.

The extra layers in the skip list are used to efficiently search for a value in it, reducing the seek time from `O(n)` to `O(logn)`.

- With only a "regular" ordered link list (no extra layers), you need on average ~n/2 iterations to find if a value exists.
- If you add a single layer, you will need half of that, meaning ~n/4 iterations.
- If you add two layers, you are going to need half of the previous, or ~n/8 average iterations.

(The above is a simplification, since you also need to traverse the next levels as well, but they remain similar complexity to the top level)

By continuing this all the way to the top, you are going to need on average `O(1)` iterations *per layer*, giving you `O(logn)` total lookup time.